# React JSX Button with Image inside, return a value on click

Tags: reactjs

So I am maping and displaying images into the dom. The images need to be clickable and then return a value, because I need to know what button was clicked so I can get the value or id and search through another array in another component. I did something like this in vanilla js by adding an id to the image and it worked but will not work in react. here is my code if anyone has a solution.

```
import {Photo, ViewProps} from "./../tools/Samples.model";

const FocusView = ({photos, visible}:ViewProps):JSX.Element => {

  const imageClick = (e:any):void => {
    console.log("image is clicked"  + e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="focusImages" style={{display: (visible ? 'flex' : 'none')}}>
      {photos.map((data:Photo,n:number):JSX.Element => {
        return (
          <button key={n} style={{background:'none', border:'none'}} onClick={imageClick} value={n}>
            <img src={"./Images/" + data.source} alt="asd" className="imageHover"/>
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
  
export default FocusView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use currying to solve this.

Something like this?

```
import {Photo, ViewProps} from "./../tools/Samples.model";

const FocusView = ({photos, visible}:ViewProps):JSX.Element => {

const imageClick = (n:number) => (e:any):void => {
  console.log("image is clicked"  + n);
}
return (
  
    
<div className="focusImages" style={{display: (visible ? 'flex' : 
'none')}}>
     {photos.map((data:Photo,n:number):JSX.Element =>{
       return (

 <button key={n} style={{background:'none', border:'none'}} 
    onClick={imageClick(n}>
         <img src={"./Images/" + data.source} alt="asd" 
            className="imageHover"/>
 </button>

       );
     })}
    </div>
 
);
```

Comment: you should wrap the function in a callback like that ```() => imageClick(n)``` so it's only executed on click

Comment: Yeah its showing n in the console correctly now, thx.

Comment: @Kakiz that is the cool thing about currying is that you do not need to do that. You are 100% correct though if we weren't currying.

Answer (score 0):

React has synthetic event. You could try the following example to get most information from the event you have clicked on.

```
const imageClick = () => {
  console.log("image is clicked"  + event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your **array index** (which you named as "n") as a **parameter** for imageClick function instead of trying to get from `event.target`

```
  photos.map((data: Photo, n: number): JSX.Element => {
      return (
         <button onClick={() => imageClick(n)}></button>
      )
  }
```